# Transformation of Uniform distribution

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics

If $U$ is a random variable with a uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ then $\mathbb{E}(U^2) = \frac{1}{3}$. Suppose $X = U^2$. Then, the PDF of $X$ is $f(x)= 1/\sqrt{x}$ for $0<x<1$, and $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{2}{3}$. Did I miss anything, because $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(U^2)$, therefore I should get the same value?

Thank you

Comment: $f(x)$ should be $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Thank you so much I got your point :)

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As pointed out by Mathaholic in a comment, there's a factor of $\frac12$ missing in the density.